# Why do I get syntax error calling object item by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Why is it when I do this:

```
var obj = { 0:"bla", 1:"blabla" }
```

`obj.0` gives me an error, and I can only do `obj[0]`?

Comment: isn't array more convenient `var arr = ["bla", "blabla"]` arr[0] // bla

Comment: you're missing a double quote there. it should be `var obj = { 0:"bla", 1:"blabla" }`

Comment: The missing quote is only here, when I ran this with the quote I still go an error

Comment: @Endless it is, but the question is more theoretical, to understand the way JS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to have a `SyntaxError` because there's a missing `"` after `bla`:

```
var obj = { 0:"bla", 1:"blabla" }
```

Anyway, `obj.0` will give you a `SyntaxError` simply because JavaScript recognizes properties accesses by the following grammar:

```
<identifier>.<identifier>
```

And identifiers in JavaScript cannot start with numbers. That's why you can't do:

```
var 1a = 1;    // SyntaxError -> Unexpected number
```

By doing `obj[0]`, JavaScript recognizes `0` as an expression and converts to the string `"0"`, respecting the rule that JavaScript objects are associative arrays, and then their properties can be accessed by their keys (which are strings) like this:

```
obj["constructor"]
```

You can read more about this in the [section 7.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) of ECMAScript Language Specification.

The following code describes the identifier syntax (taken from the link above):

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
    UnicodeLetter
    $
    _
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

Comment: true, but you can still use numbers... obj[1]

Comment: Yes, but in this case, `1` is an expression embraced with `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2):

A proper [identifier](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) must not start with a digit. It's as simple as that. Properties can only be accessed with the `.` (dot) notation if their keys are proper identifiers. Otherwise the square bracked notation must be used: `obj['0']`

`obj[0]` is identical to `obj['0']` because property keys must be strings (any string is a valid property key), therefore the value between brackets is coerced to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var obj = { 0:"bla, 1:"blabla" } //wrong
```

bla is not in double qoutes properly, so try

```
 var obj = { 0:"bla", 1:"blabla" } //correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**declare**

```
var obj = { "0":"bla", "1":"blabla" };
```

**access**

```
alert(obj[0]);
alert(obj[1]);
```